# CSVListReader read from tsv file breaks if input tsv file has ' or "

Tags: java, csv

```
List<String> list=null;
ICsvListReader listReader = null;
listReader = new CsvListReader(new FileReader(new File(folderPath+"/"+fileName)), CsvPreference.TAB_PREFERENCE);
 while((list=listReader.read())!=null) {
   System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

I am using `org.supercsv.io.ICsvListReader` but the code breaks if in the tsv input file `'` or `"` is present. Instead of six fields I am getting the 6th field as `null`. Please tell me if any changes required or some other library for reading large tsv file is there .

Data:

```
data    "city' b    state   country sdsadsd details value
```

Comment: have you tried looking at the [documentation?](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/apidocs/org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference.html) It has information on preferences that might solve your problem - but you haven't made it clear exactly what input is causing your issue. Perhaps give examples of the data that isn't working and an explanation of what you've already tried if you want someone to help.

Comment: I have read the documentation and applied CsvPreference.TAB_PREFERENCE  and I have added data above

Comment: if your data is as shown above, the opening quote `"` followed by an unmatching closing quote `'`  will cause the data to be malformed. You need to use _matching_ double quotes (`"`) when using TAB_PREFERENCE ie: `"city"    state    country    sdsadsd    details    value`

Comment: I want this data to come as it is as "city' b only to consider tab separted as separator

Comment: In csv files double quotes usually indicate the start of a field that contains either embedded quotes or data that must be escaped. _Embedded_ double quotes should be "escaped" by using two double quotes `""` inside the outer double quotes. Try with this properly formed data and see if you get the expected results: `"""city ' b"      state      country`...

Comment: thanks matt ,I have used uniVocity-parsers it parses tsv properly.

Answer (score 1):

solved it using univocity-parsers

```
        TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();

        settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");        
        TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);
        parser.beginParsing(getReader("/examples/example.tsv"));

        String[] row;
        while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
            println(out, Arrays.toString(row));
        }
```

you can refer this link
https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/examples/TsvParserExamples.java